# Set _NO_DEBUG_HEAP

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to set the _NO_DEBUG_HEAP variable in VS 2010. How do I set _NO_DEBUG_HEAP environment variable in VS 2010 ? Need some quick help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Control Panel->System Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables->System Variables.

Add a new Variable called “_NO_DEBUG_HEAP” with a value of “1”

Answer (score 22):

The previous answers were setting the var globally for all applications.

To make this setting exist only during a debug session...

in VS, you can set debugging env vars by:

1. right-click on your startup project
2. select :Properties"
3. Go to the "Debugging" property page
4. Add your var to the "Environment" property in the form varName=val. Multiple vars can be defined with one var=val pair per line.

Comment: I do not see this option for a .NET application

Comment: Use a separate C++ project that actually starts the .net binary.

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment variable within your OS

```
_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1
```

Restart Visual Studio.