# .NET/C#: How to set debugging environment variable COMPLUS_HeapVerify?

Tags: variables, windows-7

I need the heap to be verified each time the [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Tracing_garbage_collectors) (GC) finishes its work. I read this can be done by setting the environment variable `COMPLUS_HeapVerify` to `1`. But how exactly do I set this variable?

I read this can be done via **Computer/Advanced System Settings/Advanced/Environment Variables** (Windows 7), somebody tells I should set up a new *system* variable ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486282/set-no-debug-heap)), others tell this should be a *user* variable ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100543/how-do-i-set-specific-environment-variables-when-debugging-in-visual-studio)).

Is this approach correct and which (system or user) variable should be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you mentioned is absolutely correct.

1. Go to Control Panel->System Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables.
2. If you have administrator privileges, add a system variable called “COMPLUS_HeapVerify” with a value of “1”; otherwise — add the user one. Note, in the second case you might need to log out and log on.

Hope that helps.