# Porting GPUJPEG Project to Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cuda

I am currently trying to port the GPUJPEG ([on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpujpeg/)) library (based on CUDA) from Unix to Windows.

Now I am stuck - I have no idea what's happening or why it is happening, however when I run the test project, the console get's stuck on the blinky...

You can find the entire Visual Studio 2010 project (you'll need CUDA 5) here:
[wingpujpeg.zip](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6843862/wingpujpeg.zip)

I would be very happy if someone could check this out and maybe help me to port this thing to Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I want to use / create a HIGH PERFORMANCE lib for converting real time data (converting 60 fps bmp files to jpeg). This is pretty much why the "common" libraries are not of much use. It's about converting HD images to jpeg in about 10 ms... If someone has another idea, I'd, of course, like to hear it.

Comment: The code hangs in cudaMalloc() - not sure why. Tested here on my machine (Win7 64-bit with NVIDIA GTX640 (I think))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are running this from Visual Studio for debugging (F5).
If you just run it (Ctrl+F5) it should finish.

At first I thought it's some other problem (deleted my answer), but it's just too slow.
The slowness is caused by the CUDA driver calling malloc/free way too much, causing the
debug runtime allocator to slow down a lot.

This allocator by default is started when you do F5
If you want to disable it, then put in your environment settings (Properties -> Debugging -> Environment this _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1).

Look here too [Set _NO_DEBUG_HEAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486282/set-no-debug-heap)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this as soon as I'm near a CUDA-able device :-)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly an answer, but since I can't comment yet: If you're looking for an implementation of JPEG which runs on CUDA, the NPP library supports various pieces of a standard JPEG codec pipeline, and it is included with CUDA.  Check out the "jpegNPP" sample in the CUDA SDK: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/