# JPEG library in CUDA

Tags: cuda, jpeg, compression

I am trying compress and decompress images in CUDA. So far I've found this library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cuj2k/?source=navbar

But there isn't much documentation available.

Does anyone know about any well documented (with example code) JPEG compression and decompression libraries to use in CUDA?

Comment: The library you found is for JPEG2000, which is very different from JPEG. Do you know which one you want? Parts of the JPEG compression pipeline is not suitable for the GPU due to serial dependencies. I'm not sure if you would end up with an overall increase in speed for JPEG. I *think* JPEG2000 might be a better candidate for parallel compression.

Comment: You may be interested in [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615302/porting-gpujpeg-project-to-windows).

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes, I did find GPUJPEG but did not find the actually library files. Could you please lead me in the right direction?

Comment: @RogerDahl From what I've understood JPEG2000 is just a different algorithm for compression right?

Comment: @rootcage: A different, *incompatible* algorithm. JPEG uses DCT spatial compression, JPEG2000 uses wavelets. The two are not interchangeable.

Comment: I had no trouble finding the *source* files for GPUJPEG.  You will need to *build* the library, *yourself*.

Answer (score 2):

The NPP library includes building block routines for implementing a JPEG codec.  It is included as part of the CUDA distribution.  Check out the JpegNPP sample in the SDK: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/